# Idea needed to increase the performance of my logic

Tags: c#, performance, business-logic

In my application, I am creating a map for each user id which contains file ids he has access to.

Example:

User ID - 101      Data - 100100101

So for each user I am creating this file map.  When the bit is 1 then he has access to that file; otherwise he does not. But my problem is that I have 40,000,000 files.

Whenever the user searches, the corresponding user map will be loaded to produce the correct result. If I have 40,000 users, that means I need to create 40,000 map files.

How can I create a high performance implementation for this system?

Comment: Create some levels and an owner, and just attach those bits of data to the files. Then check if the user can run/read/write/ect it. Unless you are looking for something else?

Comment: Could you group users, who have access to the same set of files? Then create one map file for each group, instead of one per user.

Comment: Very confusing question. Please show some existing code/sample. Is this UNIX? And - I dare not ask - why are you doing this?

Comment: i am  creting this file then i will load into memory .. this i am doing .. i need to know whether he has access or not...

Comment: for that purpose only i am creating file.. i cant use groups thats not possible...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use common solution it is : Users, Groups of Users and Roles for Users and Groups. If you divided your logic into these 3 parts it will be more clear and understandably.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're not speaking German. But just scroll at the end of the following article: 
http://www.activevb.de/tutorials/tut_sortalgo/sortalgo.html 
and check out the project (Old VB classic).

It shows you differences between sorting algorithms. You can choose and compare. In this case, I think you can choose what hashcode (you call it map files) you can use for your application.

In any case, I would recommend to use trees if possible or sub-groups instead of one number which needs first to be parsed into 3 parametres.

Regards